# PM2 Stops app at unexpected times with SIGINT "process killed" and the reason is not clear

Tags: pm2, chron

The app stops and I can't figure out why.

I start the command like this `CMD ["pm2-runtime", "main.bundle.js", "--cron", "0 */16 * * *"]` (should mean to restar the app every 16 hours)

Then I see the app starting:

```
15:35:02
2020-01-09T15:35:02: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
15:35:03
2020-01-09T15:35:03: PM2 log: App [main.bundle:0] starting in -fork mode-
15:35:03
2020-01-09T15:35:03: PM2 log: App [main.bundle:0] online
```

And after half an hour I see that it's stopping the app.

```
16:05:32
2020-01-09T16:05:32: PM2 log: Stopping app:main.bundle id:0
16:05:32
2020-01-09T16:05:32: PM2 log: App [main.bundle:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
16:05:32
2020-01-09T16:05:32: PM2 log: pid=30 msg=process killed
16:05:32
2020-01-09T16:05:32: PM2 log: PM2 successfully stopped
```

I see no errors in my app and I can't understnad why it stops.

Another end log:

```
06:11:52
2020-01-11T06:11:52: PM2 log: Stopping app:main.bundle id:0
06:11:52
2020-01-11T06:11:52: PM2 log: App [main.bundle:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
06:11:52
2020-01-11T06:11:52: PM2 log: pid=16 msg=process killed
06:11:52
2020-01-11T06:11:52: PM2 log: PM2 successfully stopped
```